# Change rootViewController from unwindSegue

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, appdelegate, unwind-segue

I have a `MenuViewController` which is normally the `rootviewcontroller`. I use

```
- (IBAction)backToMenu:(UIStoryboardSegue*)unwindSegue {
}
```

to go back to this view controller from other view controllers. However, if the user launches the app by clicking on a local notification, the app shows `OtherViewController`. I do it like so:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {

UILocalNotification *notify = [launchOptions objectForKey:UIApplicationLaunchOptionsLocalNotificationKey];

    if (notify) {
        UIStoryboard *tip = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
        OtherViewController *viewTip = (OtherViewController *)[tip instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"OtherViewController"];
        [_window.rootViewController presentViewController:viewTip animated:YES completion:nil];
    }
}
```

The app opens at the expected OtherViewController, but then when I click the `menu button` that normally triggers the `unwindSegue`, I can't go back to `MenuViewController`. Any thoughts on how to fix this?

Edit: I use push segue to go from `MenuViewController` to `OtherViewController`.

Comment: what did you implement in you `backToMenu` IBOutlet ?

Comment: You mean in    - (IBAction)backToMenu:(UIStoryboardSegue*)unwindSegue {
}? Nothing, I just use the menu button in OtherViewController's exit as an action segue.

Comment: had you link this IBOutlet to exit in your Storyboard?

Comment: Yes, I did, and if I launch the app normally from the MenuViewController and then go to OtherViewController and click on menu button, it goes back to menu. So, there is no problem there. Only if the app launches from OtherViewController, I can't go to MenuViewController.

Comment: Instead of PresentViewController Push the View Controller or make use of PerformSegueWithIdentifier .....

Comment: I don't want to use push, because based on my experience, going back and forth between view controllers via push causes memory growth.

Comment: So you think presenting View Controller won't eat your memory :D

Comment: I use present only once in app delegate, but if I push back from other to main, instead of unwindSegue, the user may go back and forth between view controllers and this causes memory growth. That's what I found by profiling the app. Or maybe I misunderstood your point?

Comment: How can you push back viewcontroller when you have presented dismiss the Viewcontroller..